# Tomar el valor del parametro de una function que esta en un evento onclick y guardarlo en una variable

Tags: javascript, funciones, variables

Tengo una tabla en la cual muestro una serie de datos de clientes, me gustaría que al presionar un boton tome el valor de los parametro a los cuales se le están refiriendo con el evento onclik, ya logré mediante php que ese parametro sea dinámico, solo ocupo que al hacer clik en ese botón se haga referencia a dichos parametros.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="jalaid(3,dolares)"> <i class="fa fa-check"> </i></button>
```

En este caso sería lo que esta dentro de de los paréntesis en jalaid ---->(3)

ya intenté, con este código:

```
function jalaid(id,moneda){
var ndoc = id;
var mon = moneda;
//console.log(id);
document.getElementById("idprestamo").value = ndoc;
document.getElementById("moneda").value = mon;
```

}

sin embargo no funciona.

Comment: Eso pasa porque el valor de moneda debe estar entre comillas. Tendrías que ponerlo así :  jalaid(3,'dolares' )

Comment: Efectivamente, gracias. Luego de buscar en varios foros me dí cuenta de eso, y me fije que si servía

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function jalaid(id){
//aquí se puede usar el valor de id
  alert(id);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="jalaid(30)">Click aquí</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono de manera correcta

Comment: Ahora ocupo pasar dos parametros, siguiendo la misma lógica debería funcionar pero no es así, alguien podria ayudarme?

Comment: // Este es mi código
function jalaid(id, moneda){
    var ndoc = id;
    var mon = moneda;
    //console.log(id);
    //console.log(mon);
    document.getElementById("idprestamo").value = ndoc;
    document.getElementById("moneda").value = mon;
}

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es cargar específicamente un valor de una seria de datos y tienes un botón por cada fila, puedes hacerlo mediante un campo input con el atributo hidden (oculto), de esta manera al serializar el formulario a través de la identificación del botón podrás saber cual es la linea que se esta posteando, los campos input dentro de un formulario se pueden postear por eso son necesarios.

```
<form action"" metod="POST" name="formulario" id="formulario">
<input name="txt_id" id="txt_id" hidden type="text" value="<?=$varable;?>">
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="jalaid(3)"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
<input name="txt_id2" id="txt_id2" hidden type="text" value="<?=$varable2;?>">
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="jalaid(4)"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
</form>
```

Es la única manera que se me ocurre para que puedas identificar que linea estas posteando.

saludos.